# I want the sound to stop when the user clicks the home button, but not when a new content view is called

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

The onStop method and onPause method is called whenever the home button is pressed and when calling setContentView. I want to be able to differentiate between the two to when the home button is pressed, the sound stops and when a new view is set, the sound continues. I'm a noob to java, but I have searched for a long time and can't find a solution.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (btnSound.isChecked()){
        snd.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    snd.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your question, the time between both the calls between onResume() and onStop() calls, might be so narrow that, you are not able to differentiate. You can try this if you may:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    snd.start(); // Sound start

     // SLEEP 2 SECONDS HERE ...
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             snd.pause();
         } 
    }, 2000); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code you provided waits 2 seconds before pausing the sound on home button click and setting a new content view. I was looking for a solution to differentiate between home button click and switching to a new content view.

Comment: It seems that the onPause and onStop methods are called whether I click on the home button or start a new content view, so there's still no way to tell whether or not I clicked the home button or started a new activity :((((